# Возможно ли сделать очистку сообщений за заданный период времени? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

Здравствуйте искал в интернете но не нашел... Возможно ли сделать очистку сообщений например за последние 2 недели?

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=None)
```

Из этого кода который выше? (что бы указывать в аргумент например, 7d (7дней) ) и будут очищенны сообщения в канале за последние 7 дней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `lambda` функцию:

```
check=lambda m: m.created_at.day - datetime.datetime.now().day <= {ваши дни}
```

created_at - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at